# Choose coupled columns and values in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 9 variables : ID, diff2.1, diff3.1, date1, date2, date3, m1,m2,m3. I also know that m1 is coupled (associated) with date 1, same for m2 and date2, and m3 and date3. Based on different conditions from diff2.1 and diff3.1, I used case_when to create and populate m4. m4 contains values from m1,m2,m3. Now I want to create date4 column whereby the date chosen to populate this column is associated with the value in column m4. In other words, if the value in m4 of a given observation comes from m1, I want date4 column to have the value that comes from date1. if the value in m4 of another given observation comes from m3, I want date4 column to have the value that comes from date3. And so on. Thank you in advance!

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('1','2','3'),
                 diff2.1 = c(28, 91, 90),
                 diff3.1 = c(140, 92, 91),
                 date1 = ymd(c('2014-10-12', '2014-06-01', '2015-02-10')),
                 date2 = as.Date(c('2015-10-17', '2014-06-06', '2015-04-20')),
                 date3 = as.Date(c('', '2014-08-13', '2015-12-01')),
                 m1 = c('4','4','10'),
                 m2 = c('3', '0', ' 1'),
                 m3 = c('10', '7', '5'))

df_new<- df%>%mutate(m4 = case_when(diff3.1 >= diff2.1 & diff3.1 < 91 ~ pmax(m1,m2,m3),
                                   diff3.1 > diff2.1 & diff3.1 > 90 & diff2.1 > 90 ~ m1,
                                   diff3.1 > diff2.1 & diff3.1 > 90 & diff2.1 < 91 ~  pmax(m1,m2)))
```

If I were to create column date4, I would like to have : 2014-10-12 for ID1, 2014-06-01 for ID2, 2015-02-10 for ID3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strategy will work

- using `rowwise()`
- extracted index of `date` column using `match(m4,..` with `c_across(starts_with('m'))`
- pasted that result with `date` to `get` the columnname desired

Other things are clear enough

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = c('1','2','3'),
                 diff2.1 = c(28, 91, 90),
                 diff3.1 = c(140, 92, 91),
                 date1 = ymd(c('2014-10-12', '2014-06-01', '2015-02-10')),
                 date2 = as.Date(c('2015-10-17', '2014-06-06', '2015-04-20')),
                 date3 = as.Date(c('', '2014-08-13', '2015-12-01')),
                 m1 = c('4','4','10'),
                 m2 = c('3', '0', ' 1'),
                 m3 = c('10', '7', '5'))

df_new<- df%>%mutate(m4 = case_when(diff3.1 >= diff2.1 & diff3.1 < 91 ~ pmax(m1,m2,m3),
                                    diff3.1 > diff2.1 & diff3.1 > 90 & diff2.1 > 90 ~ m1,
                                    diff3.1 > diff2.1 & diff3.1 > 90 & diff2.1 < 91 ~  pmax(m1,m2)))

df_new %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(date4 = get(paste0('date', match(m4, c_across(starts_with('m'))))))
# A tibble: 3 x 11
# Rowwise: 
  ID    diff2.1 diff3.1 date1      date2      date3      m1    m2    m3    m4    date4     
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <date>    
1 1          28     140 2014-10-12 2015-10-17 NA         4     "3"   10    4     2014-10-12
2 2          91      92 2014-06-01 2014-06-06 2014-08-13 4     "0"   7     4     2014-06-01
3 3          90      91 2015-02-10 2015-04-20 2015-12-01 10    " 1"  5     10    2015-02-10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>